# Python matrix tagging

Tags: python

I have an algorithm I want to implement and I'm trying to figure out the best way to do it.
I have a matrix H of size mxn (m - number of last inputs - sliding window, n - number of attributes).
I have a set of attributes A, and I want to find correlations between the attributes.
My problem is how can I tag a matrix column/line with a name?
this is the algorithm I'm trying to implement:
[image]

attributes a_i, a_j are extracted from H and denoted as H_i^T ,H_j^T (where T denotes transpose).
We then apply the Pearson correlation on them denoted as ρi,j.

for example:
If we have:

```
H(mxn = 4x3) = IQ Height weight
               30 180 80
               30 170 60
               40 183 85
               10 190 95

ct = 0.7
A = {IQ, Height, Weight}

Then the result we should get is:
CS = {(C,0)}
Where C = {Height, Weight}
```

I would also love to get any visualiztion tools reccomandations.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: can you post an example matrix with data and then the expected output?

Comment: Added. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Pandas is your best friend when it comes to tabular data. I'm not an expert on linear algebra notation but it seems like what you're trying to do is append a tuple into a set if the two items in the tuple are correlated by more than the threshold value, ie. if Height and Weight have a correlation coefficient > 0.7, then add those two values into list CS. I would do something like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
"IQ":[30,30,40,10], 
"Height":[180,170,183,190,], 
"Weight":[80,60,85,95]
})

lst = []
threshold = 0.7
p_arr = df.corr().to_dict()

for attr in p_arr:
    for sub_attr in p_arr[attr]:
        p = p_arr[attr][sub_attr]
        if attr != sub_attr and p > threshold:
            lst.append(((attr, sub_attr), p))
```

produces:

```py
[(('Height', 'Weight'), 0.9956654266839726),
 (('Weight', 'Height'), 0.9956654266839726)]
```

and for correlation heatmap

```py
sns.heatmap(df.corr())
```

Comment: what IDE are you using and do you have matplotlib and seaborn installed?

Comment: pycharm and yes both installed.

Comment: Normally the console will generate a .png or something, but have you tried https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/matplotlib-support.html ?